# Web page refresh - does it reload elements (like images) that haven't changed?

Tags: html

This may sound like a newbie question but I looked for an answer and couldn't find one.

So, what happens exactly when one hits the refresh button ? The result is that all elements of the page, including the page itself, are refreshed, that much is clear. But the question is, if an element, say an image, hasn't changed, is it loaded again from the server ?
I assume it's not the case. It would be plain stupid. But I couldn't find a place that clearly and authoritatively states this, so I'd be grateful if somebody could provide that. Also, is this the standard behavior across all browsers or are there exceptions ?

update: I have found some useful info here

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3

I'm not going to give this as an answer because it isn't about refreshing but about validating a stale cache entry. But I really see no reason that refreshing wouldn't work on the same principles. I guess a hard refresh will fetch the resource no matter what, and a soft refresh will only get entries that have changed. It would appear to be the reasonable thing to do. Hopefully somebody more knowledgeable will confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when a webpage is reloaded *normally* (`cmd` + `r` on Mac), the browser pulls the webpage from its cache, which is its short-term memory. If you force a *hard reload*, or *empty cache*, (`cmd` + `alt/option` + `r` on Mac), then the page is re-downloaded from the server. This is so the computer can save storage space and bandwidth. So in a nutshell, pressing the refresh button pulls the page out of the browser's short-term memory. [Here's](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-we-hit-refresh-on-a-web-page) a very good explanation that you might want for a much more in-depth analysis if you want it as well.

Comment: I had found your link myself (thanks nevertheless for posting it). It's very complicated and it doesn't directly and plainly address my question. I don't know about Mac, but pressing F5 on Windows does reload all images, .js files etc. from the server, right ? I'm pretty sure it does. I don't really get it what would be the point if it didn't.

Comment: Does my answer fix your question though @VSim?

Comment: Not really. But let;s say I'm talking about a hard reload. What happens then with elements such as images that haven't changed ?

Comment: @VSim Then they *are* redownloaded from the server, as the browser isn't sure if the page has changed or not (static page or dynamic page). So caching (normal reload) pulls image from memory and it doesn't change. Hard reload (empty cache) pulls the image from the server, treating it as a new image. Better?

Comment: But are they brought entirely from the server ? The browser could ask the server via a CRC or something if the image (which could be very large) has changed or not. And if not, use the cache version. I have done some tests on Windows (7) and it appears to be like this. It would also be what I'd expect.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Large images are sometimes stored permanently in cache, so that would make sense.